# Как скрыть определенные поля у AR объекта?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Самый простой пример - поля, связанные с данными о пароле и прочим у гема Devise. То есть когда вы прописываете `User.first`, то вы не получите "секретную" информацию о пользователе.

Мне нужно проделать схожее с некоторыми моделями и полями. Цель? Повышение безопасности в конкретной среде. Вообще хочется добиться такого результата, чтобы невозможно было получить данные из БД.

Вот простой пример:

> Есть таблица `users`, которая содержит в себе поле `email`. Например, если при деплое переменная окружения `SECRET_EMAIL` имеет значение `true`, то я хочу чтобы отдаваемое значение маскировалось. Для этого я хочу заблокировать получение информации из этого поля из БД (то есть как-будто этого поля нет в БД), а затем внутри модели описать метод `email` и внутри уже сделать что-то свое.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я могу почитать об этом, есть ли в Rails (AR) готовый механизм для скрытия?

Comment: Сразу скажу, что механизма подобного рода я не встречал. Отмечу лишь, что если некто запустил консоль rails, то вряд ли "механическое" ограничение экземпляра ActiveRecord на вывод каких-либо полей поможет скрыть "секретную" информацию. Например потому, что данные из таблицы можно запрашивать в "сыром" виде с помощью метода SomeMode.connection.select_all('select * from some_table')

Comment: @Nik понял вас. И согласен с вами - такая себе затея...

Answer (score 0):

Использовать `default_scope` в определении модели. Например мы хотим получать только `login` у модели `User`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr = [:login]
  default_scope { select(attr) }
  ...
end
```

В `attr` присвоить массив с атрибутами, которые Вы хотите получать для этой модели.